# How to add text to a title without it appearing in the reference?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I'm trying to make a section title with additional information next to it. Currently I'm simply changing the style and adding the text directly to the section title but it has the unintended side effect of being included when I \nameref it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section One {\footnotesize \textnormal A section of important stuff}\label{sec1}}
 Stuff for the section goes here.

\section*{Another Section}
 I try to reference \nameref{sec1} and I get the complete title, while I only want to see "Section Title"

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome, very good example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I've defined two new commands, `\runinsec` and `\aftersec`, the former to be used instead of `section` when you want sections like this and the latter to insert the information in the same line of the section title.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\runinsec{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {3.5ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                   {-1em}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\aftersec[1]{\begingroup\normalfont\footnotesize\bfseries #1\endgroup%
                        \par\nobreak\vspace*{2.3ex}\noindent\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\runinsec*{Section One}\label{sec1}\aftersec{A section of important stuff}
 Stuff for the section goes here.

\section*{Another Section}
 I try to reference \nameref{sec1} and I get the complete title, while I only want to see "Section Title"

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! Bonus points for not using titlesec.

Comment: @AgentJWall You're welcome.